# How can I change style of p:panelGrid for odd columns?

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I work with jsf 2.2 and primefaces, I have realise many layers (xhtml files).

From my **p:datalist**, when I select one row, I display : Edit, Creat or View Dialog, from this code (List.xhtml) :

```
<ui:composition template="/templateUser.xhtml">
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="RefTableListForm">
        <p:panel header="#{bundle.Title}">
            <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{beanController.items}" var="item" ... >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton "/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton "/>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_idAvis}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{item.idAvis}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_libAvis}"/></f:facet><h:outputText value="#{item.libAvis}"/>
                </p:column>
                
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="#{bundle.Create}" actionListener="#{beanController.prepareCreate}" update=":RefTableCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('RefTableCreateDialog').show()"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="viewButton"   icon="ui-icon-search" value="#{bundle.View}" update=":RefTableViewForm" oncomplete="PF('RefTableViewDialog').show()" disabled="#{empty beanController.selected}"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="editButton"   icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="#{bundle.Edit}" update=":RefTableEditForm" oncomplete="PF('RefTableEditDialog').show()" disabled="#{empty beanController.selected}"/>
                    <ui:remove>
                    <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"  value="#{bundle.Delete}" actionListener="#{beanController.destroy}" update=":growl,datalist" disabled="#{empty beanController.selected}"/>
                    </ui:remove>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <ui:include src="Create.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="Edit.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="View.xhtml"/>
</ui:define></ui:composition>
```

But now, I would change all my **ODD** columns of my all **p:panelGrid** with **bold font**, if is it possible ?

In my css file, I try this code to put all my odd columns in bold font :

```
.ui-panelgrid tr  {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

But don't work for **View Dialog** all his columns are bold, with this code (View.xhtml) :

```
<ui:composition>
<p:dialog id="RefTableViewDlg" widgetVar="RefTableViewDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="#{bundle.Title}">
    <h:form id="RefTableViewForm">
        <h:panelGroup id="display">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{beanController.selected != null}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Label_idAvis}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{beanController.selected.idAvis}" title="#{bundle.Title_idAvis}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Label_libAvis}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{beanController.selected.libAvis}" title="#{bundle.Title_libAvis}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Close}" onclick="RefTableViewDialog.hide()"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog></ui:composition>
```

And my genereted html for View Dialog is:

```
   <html>
<form id="RefTableViewForm" name="RefTableViewForm" method="post"  >
<input type="hidden" name="RefTableViewForm" value="RefTableViewForm" />
<span id="RefTableViewForm:display">
<table id="RefTableViewForm:j_idt56" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">IdAvis:</td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><span title="IdAvis">08</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">LibAvis:</td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><span title="LibAvis">REGLEMENT PAR COMPTE DEVISES</span></td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="RefTableViewForm:j_idt63"  />
</form>
</html>
```

But from Edit or Create Dialog, i get this generated html :

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="j_idt51" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget" for="idAvis">IdAvis:</label></td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><input id="idAvis" name="idAvis" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="IdAvis" /></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you for your help and advice !

Comment: Does this render tr elements inside of a table in the finished HTML page for you? I need to know to be able to answer.

Comment: thank you,  this render elements are inside <ui:composition>, <p:dialog>, <h:panelGroup> and <p:panelGrid>

Comment: Yes. If this code doesn't generate any tr elements there will be nothing for the css to select to begin with, and I need to be sure that my answer is at all applicable before I send it. If you can, please use the "view page source" option after right-clicking in your page where you see the entire table in bold. Because of the possible length I would recommend [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) to include the html code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS sets the font weight to bold on every table row contained in an element with the class ui-panelgrid. This might be good in some cases, though in order to have every odd row styled like you want, there is a pseudo class inside of CSS that can help: [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). You can pass a number, even, odd or a function of the form An+B to this, and it will select rows accordingly. The functional argument selects every A child starting at an offset of B from 0.

In order to get every odd table row in bold, you can use this:

```
.ui-panelgrid tr:nth-child(odd) {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

or, optionally using the function, this:

```
.ui-panelgrid tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

This selects every odd tr residing inside of elements with the class ui-panelgrid and should change the rows of your table the way you had planned. **Please note, though, that not all browsers may support this, depending on how old the version they are running is. Refer to the [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) also linked above for more information on that.**

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly with both solutions ! I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I would appreciate if you could accept my answer as the solution to your question, too.

Comment: Someone has done that, at least, so it's good now!